# The MS Teams web client continuously redirects to the login page after logging in, creating a frustrating loop of repeated login attempts

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I have been successfully using MS Teams on Chrome without any issues. However, today I encountered a problem where every time I attempt to log in, it redirects me back to the login page, creating an infinite loop.

Despite my attempts to add related websites to the "always allow cookies" list, it did not solve the issue.`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-sign-in/sign-in-loop`

Comment: Is there any console error you are getting? We tried at our end, but this works fine for us in chrome.

Comment: Proven; Cairo, Egypt, found only on Windows 10 (1809, 22H1), on all browsers: latest Firefox, latest Firefox Dev, latest Chrome, latest Seamonkey.

Comment: The dreaded loop ended around 2023.05.29 12:00 UTC, on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by deleting this data, but need to do this once per week minimum:
[image]

Comment: Posting images on Stack Overflow is discouraged and while this image may be helpful to show the entry it in the UI of the browser you should also add details like which data and in which configuration page of the browser you have deleted into the text of your answer.